# How to prevent Maven project from downloading specific dependencies?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml, war

I wanted to remove all direct / transitive dependencies using older log4J version, particularly version `1.27.1` from my project.

I have made sure that my project's `pom.xml` and `lib` folder does not contain `log4J 1.27.1`.

However, whenever the project builds into a `.war` file, there are some other libraries in my project which is still using `log4j 1.27.1` resulting in `log4j-1.27.1.jar` being downloaded into the build for deployment.

Is there any means we can force the Maven project by preventing it from downloading a specific dependency? For example, by adding some
configurations to the `pom.xml` file?

---

**Edit 1**: Understand that one way to do it is to do exclusions in the `pom.xml` file. But that requires me to explicitly mention all the artifacts . Is there anyway to do it as though I am stating `"hey, I don't want to see log4j-1.27.1.jar downloaded in my Maven project at all, be it any artifact is depending on it"` ?

Comment: See the maven dependency exclusion block as documented here. https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

Comment: I have thought about using exclusion, but with that I need to explicitly mention all the artifacts and exclude then one by one? Are there any ways we can exclude a specific dependency without mentioning all the artifacts? Or explicit exclusion on each artifact is the only way to do it?

Comment: I would suggest to use maven-enforcer-plugin to prevent any use of particular libs/versions https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/bannedDependencies.html or https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/banTransitiveDependencies.html

Answer (score 5):

Use the enforcer plugin to ban all unsecure log4j versions. Any use will fail your build and tell you where it's being used, allowing you to overwrite the log4j dependency with a secure version or exclude it altogether.

From Gunnar Morling's gist (warning: update the log4j minimum version here [to the log4j version with no vulnerabilities reported](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core)):

```
<!-- plug-in configuration to put into your parent POM for avoiding any usages of
     outdated log4j2 versions, some of which are subject to the RCE CVE-2021-44228
     ("Log4Shell"), CVE-2021-45046, and CVE-2021-45105. Make sure to check for the
     latest version of log4j2 at
     https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
...
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>ban-bad-log4j-versions</id>
      <phase>validate</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>enforce</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <rules>
          <bannedDependencies>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:(,2.17.0)</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </bannedDependencies>
        </rules>
        <fail>true</fail>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```