# How to block a maven dependency from getting downloaded

Tags: java, maven, security, sonarqube

I want to block a library so that developers are not able to download any old version of library or some libraries altogether.
Maven has a [enforcer plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70740248/how-to-prevent-maven-project-from-downloading-specific-dependencies) but we cant enforce everyone to use it at enterprise level.
I am looking for a solution which can block this even if it is mention in the POM. Want to fail the build if blocked library is present.
I am exploring multiple solution either at maven level or by using some scanning tools.
Objective is to do it as early as possible. Artifact scanning is one way but it happens after the build when artifacts are generated which is waste of time.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: Repository Manager level is the right way to go...

Answer (score 0):

Really, the only way you can actually control this is by controlling the firewall and the intranet repository.  Don't allow direct access to public repositories, only allow the use of a supported intranet repository within the firewall, which has controlled and monitored access to public repositories.